# Explanation of BigInteger 'multiplyToLen' Function

Tags: java, biginteger

While working on a large integer implementation of my own, I looked through Java's BigInteger source in order to gain further understanding of multiplication algorithms, and focused mainly on `multiplyToLen()`.

Overall, the function seems to take on the general gradeschool multiplication algorithm apporach, but I cannot understand key parts of it.

First, the algorithm goes through this first loop, where x and y are the two numbers being multiplied, and z is the product:

```
int xstart = xlen - 1;
int ystart = ylen - 1;

...

for (int j=ystart, k=ystart+1+xstart; j >= 0; j--, k--) {
    long product = (y[j] & LONG_MASK) * (x[xstart] & LONG_MASK) + carry;
    z[k] = (int)product;
    carry = product >>> 32;
}

z[xstart] = (int)carry;
```

Then, it goes onto the next loop, that seems a lot closer to the gradeschool algorithm.

```
for (int i = xstart-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    carry = 0;
    for (int j=ystart, k=ystart+1+i; j >= 0; j--, k--) {
        long product = (y[j] & LONG_MASK) * (x[i] & LONG_MASK) +
                               (z[k] & LONG_MASK) + carry;
        z[k] = (int)product;
        carry = product >>> 32;
    }

    z[i] = (int)carry;
}
```

I have tried tracing both loops using decimal numbers to no avail, and I cannot grasp the function of the first loop versus the second loop.

What part of the multiplication algorithm is being done in the first loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop multiplies two integers (one from each BigInteger `x` and `y` respectively) and then **stores** the lower 32 bits of the results in the result array `z`. The higher 32 bits are used as carry for the next higher pair of integers from `x` and `y` resp.

The other loops do almost the same, but they have to **add the results to the integers already stored in the `z` array**, so they are not as simple as the first one.

The bit fiddling with the `long`s and the `LONG_MASK` is only there to treat the integers as **unsigned** 32 bit values (Java does generally not know unsigned integers) by promoting them to 64 bit integers and then masking the lower 32 bits to get unsigned 32 bit values. The 64 bit multiplication results disregard any overflow in bit 63. The lower bits are stored (*loop 1*) or added (*other loops*) to the already calculated results from previous loops, found in `z`. The top 32 bits are used as carry for the next iteration.

---

*This is how it is generally done. My Delphi code for BigIntegers does the same, and IIRC, that is also the algorithm that Knuth shows in his Art Of Computer Programming (vol II).*

Comment: Knuth doesn't have the two loops. You can do it all in one. There must be some advantage to doing the lowest digit of `x` separately first, but offhand I can't see what it is.

Comment: The first loop would only be adding to all zeros. That‘s futile, and avoiding the add in the first loop is a little faster.